# Linebreaks in MetaUML

Tags: metauml

I'm trying to draw an UML diagram with MetaUML for my LaTeX document. Unfortunatly I'm a little bit dissatisfied with the layout because functions with a long signature (i.e. many parameters) become quite long lines and therefore overly broaden the drawn box of the class in which they are in, so I want to make MetaUML split up those long lines.

Is there a way to get a linebreak into attributes of a MetaUML `class` object?

The handbook does not say anything about it. I need to incorporate my method signatures, but without linebreaks they would make my classes way to wide for readable diagram.
A short example (*note*: the LaTeX builder has to be run with `-shell-escape` option):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shellescape]{gmp}
\begin{document}
\begin{mpost}[mpsettings={input metauml;},use]

Class.Config("Config")
("-key1:char*","-value1:char*","-key2:char*","-value2:char*","-key3:char*","-value3:char*","-key4:char*","-value4:char*","-key5:char*","-value5:char*")
("+setValues(key1:char*,value1:char*, key2:char*,value2:char*, key3:char*,value3:char*,key4:char*,value4:char*,key5:char*,value5:char*)");
drawObjects(Config);

\end{mpost}
\end{document}
```

Doing so, the line for function `setvalues()` becomes pretty long and, thus, the drawing of the class in the diagram becomes overly wide.
I want to put something like a `\newline` or `\\` in between key3 and value3 in order for the function being distributed over two lines and the drawing becomes a little more compact.
While this is, semantically speaking, of course not a sensible example, I think it's getting my point across: I basically want to split overlong lines in classes of the UML diagram.

Comment: Did you mean to ask this on stackoverflow, it seems off topic for this TeX typesetting system site?

Comment: If the question is about typesetting with the Metapost package, please edit your question with an example of code and we'll reopen it.

Comment: Hi, it's indeed about typesetting. I want to add a line break in a `Class` box of an UML diagram included in a LaTeX document.

Comment: Sorry, but that's very far from being an example; can you add what's needed to be fed to Metapost and compiled?

Comment: Of course, no big deal.
I just added a better one, embedded in LaTex, as did it in my actual document. I hope it's a little bit clearer now what I want to (and unfortunately can't) do...

Comment: I don't think it's possible; MetaUML uses Metapost strings, not `btex...etex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to have the attributes and methods on multiple lines, for example:

```
Class.A("Point")
  ("#x:int", 
   "#y:int")
  ("+set(x:int, y:int)",
   "+getX():int",
   "+getY():int",
   "-debug():void",
   "test():void");
drawObject(A);
```

A long method string may be built from its parts using the Metapost string concatenation operator '&', as in "f(" & ")".

https://github.com/ogheorghies/MetaUML/blob/master/manual/fig/class.mp#L21

Comment: This shows different attributes on different lines, but the question appears to ask how to have the same attribute on multiple lines. Is that possible?

Comment: @Paul: Yes, the contents of various attributes or methods may be identical.

Comment: The string concatenation operator you mention is a way for getting the information on two lines in the UML code. The original question (which I also have) is how to get a single method or member in the output diagram on two lines **after** it is processed in mpost. The code in the MWE have many attributes in the method that would make an output diagram go off the page in his LaTeX document.